# ErrImageNeverPull server gave http response to https client

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I have 1 master node and 1 worker node of Kubernetes. I created a local registry for my docker images and I pulled it to: `myiplocal:5000/xxx` in the master node.

When I create the deployment it is giving error:

> Failed to pull image "myip:5000/xxx:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "myip:5000/xxx:latest": failed to resolve reference "myip:5000/xxx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://myip:5000/v2/xxx/manifests/latest": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

I tried to pull it manually in my worker using  docker pull `myip:5000/xxx`
and it worked, so. Why it's not working when I deploy the .yaml?

.yaml important info:

```
 containers:
        - name: xxx
          image: myip:5000/xxx
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: xxx-secret
```

I created daemon.json in a worker using:

```
{
 "insecure-registries": [ "myip:5000" ]
}
```

The problem is that still gives me the error of https client.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your local registry is running on http url instead of https, and k8s is making https connection while fetching image,

Can you try accessing the local registry with both
secured => https://myip:5000/ and,
unsecured url => http://myip:5000/
on your browser, and check if this resolves

Comment: using curl i can access when it is http but not https, so how could i say to k8s to use http instead https?